# Automated UI test naming Convention

Tags: automated-tests, naming-conventions, standards, ui-testing, testautomationfx

I need to use standard naming convention for UI test cases. When i am investigating this, i found naming convention for Unit testing. but my scenario is different.

I have main three projects, 1 web client, 2 windows application and mobile application. i tried to test functional flows of these applications. Eg. Select the shipment from menu add details and save the shipment.

There are so many functional flows. some flows are different based on selected value on comboBox (Shipment Type). test cases also will be written by different testers. So can any one suggest me a good readable pattern. because i don't want two people write same again and again but if the name is too lengthy, they wont interest on it.

I found one convention  like
if the item on the menu in powerpoint (MS_PPT_mHome_Copy). mHome means the Menu home.

However can you suggest alternate best standard naming convention which use to UI Test case.

Hope you valuable suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

If you have divided well your UI test suites, you can skip the part of the naming which points the *functionality*. In my experience we've used such naming conventions for the UI tests:

```
PageSectionElementAction
```

Also some test cases should be created from the user stories as well. So reusing the UserStory name is a way to go too, or combine it with the rest of the

> functional flow